# Kivy on BeagleBone Black: ImportError: No module named window_x11

Tags: python, kivy, beagleboneblack

I am trying to use Kivy on the BeagleBone Black Rev. C running Debian Jessie. I have installed kivy according to the documentation here:

https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html

and installed via aptitude. When I test for it using python >> import kivy, it works. However when I run my app I get the following error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-06_5.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:48:22) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name bcm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - RuntimeError: No available video device
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "_window_sdl2.pyx", line 80, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1810)
  File "_window_sdl2.pyx", line 55, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1460)

x11 - ImportError: No module named window_x11
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I have also installed cython and pygame for good measure. They also test as being installed. But I haven't been able to run my Kivy app.

I have been stuck for a while...any suggestions?

Comment: It might be related to this issue: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3002
Try running `aptitude update` followed by a `aptitude full-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

BBB is not an officially supported platform for Kivy. See https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4153